# How do closures differ between foreach and list.ForEach()?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach, closures

Consider this code.

```
        var values = new List<int> {123, 432, 768};

        var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();

        values.ForEach(v=>funcs.Add(()=>v));

        funcs.ForEach(f=>Console.WriteLine(f()));//prints 123,432,768

        funcs.Clear();

        foreach (var v1 in values)
        {
            funcs.Add(()=>v1);
        }

        foreach (var func in funcs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(func());  //prints 768,768,768
        }
```

I know that the second foreach prints 768 3 times because of the closure variable captured by the lambda. why does it not happen in the first case?How does `foreach` keyword different from the method `Foreach`? Is it beacuse the expression is evaluated when i do `values.ForEach`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`foreach` only introduces *one* variable. While the lambda parameter variable is "fresh" each time it is invoked.

Compare with:

```
foreach (var v1 in values) // v1 *same* variable each loop, value changed
{
   var freshV1 = v1; // freshV1 is *new* variable each loop
   funcs.Add(() => freshV1);
} 

foreach (var func in funcs)
{
   Console.WriteLine(func()); //prints 123,432,768
}
```

That is,

```
foreach (T v in ...) { }
```

can be thought of as:

```
T v;
foreach(v in ...) {}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that in the `foreach` loop, you've got a *single* variable `v1` which is captured. That variable takes on each value within `values` - but you're only *using* it at the end... which means we only see the final value each time.

In your `List<T>.ForEach` version, each iteration introduces a new variable (the parameter `f`) - so each lambda expression is capturing a separate variable, which never changes in value.

Eric Lippert has [blogged about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) - but note that this behaviour *may* change in future versions of C#.

Comment: I understand the `foreach` semantics. But in `List<T>.ForEach` do you mean the variable `v` as in the third line is newly created for every iteration?

Comment: @Ashley: Yes, because it's the parameter for the lambda expression. Even if you invoked the same delegate twice and the lambda expression *modified* the value, it wouldn't make any difference - because it's not a captured variable, just a delegate parameter.

Comment: @Jon, is it possible for them to change that behavior without introducing major regressions?

Comment: @FuleSnabel: Any code using that behaviour is already highly likely to be broken. My beef with it is that it allows you to write code which behaves *correctly* in C# 5 (say) but will compile and behave *badly* in earlier versions. But maybe that's a price worth paying.

Comment: @FuleSnabel: We are likely to take the breaking change in the next version. The question is whether the regression will be "major". I think not; as Jon correctly notes, programs that depend on this behaviour are probably already broken.

Comment: @Eric: I assume it will be compile-time breaks not run-time breaks? How would I resolve the breaks if I have any? Introducing a scoped variable inside the for loop as I do in C#3+?

Comment: @FuleSnabel: the "breaking change" will be that recompiling a C# 4 program (that is probably already wrong) will give different results when compiled in C# 5. There shouldn't be any runtime change.

Comment: @Eric: Is there a plan for warning anyone compiling code which is intended to work with both C# 4 and C# 5? (I'm thinking primarily of open source projects, where there's no guarantee that all contributors will be using the same version of VS.) I know we've discussed this before - just wondered what the current thinking was.

Comment: @Jon: No firm plan. I'll mention it to the C# 5 guys and see if any thinking has evolved here.