# Why is a temporary variable required in foreach to be included in lambda expression?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, iqueryable

I was reading `C# 4 in a Nutshell` and I've come to this piece of code:

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  IQueryable<Product> query = dataContext.Products;

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    query = query.Where (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return query;
}
```

Right after the code there's a 'warning' that goes like this:

`The temporary variable in the loop is required to avoid the outer variable trap, where the same variable is captured for each iteration of the foreach loop.`

I don't get it, I don't understand why the `temp` variable is necessary. What is the `outter variable trap`?

From: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Can anybody please clarify this?

Comment: You definitely want to read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Everybody suggested the same blog post, how come I've never heard of Eric before? thanks all

Comment: @sebastian: We can't know why you haven't heard of him before, but you've got a lot of catching up to do. Eric's blog is a *treasure trove*. Have an enjoyable few months reading it :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133816 (the culprit is `foreach`)

Comment: I've written a FxCop rule for that (it's in fxcopcontrib on codeplex) but it isn't fully polished yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is only *one* variable called `keyword` that is closed over. The temporary variable, however, is *different* each iteration.

Thus, without the temporary variable, when the lambda is *executed later*, `keyword` evaluates to the last value it was assigned in the loop.

Another solution, in some cases, is to *force* the evaluation (and end up with a `List` or such).

Comment: `later`, that's the keyword! I didn't see that, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `keyword` is changing. The `=>` delegate closes on the *current* value of the variable, not the value it had back in the past when the delegate was created. There's a detailed explanation in [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

This classic C bug is the same mistake:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h>

void * MyThreadFunction(void *x)
{
   printf("I am thread %d\n", * (int *) x);
   return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
   int i;
   pthread_t t[10];
   void *ret;
   for(i=0; i<10; i++)
       pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, MyThreadFunction, (void *) &i);
   for(i=0; i<10; i++)
       pthread_join(t[i], &ret);
}
```

The `* (int *) x` gets the *current* value of `i`, not the value when the thread was created.

Comment: That's a nice article, but it annoys me there is not a small excerpt / summary that can be used with minimal context in it :(