# Blazor Component Rerender

Tags: blazor

```
   @foreach ((Employee, int) result in searchResults)
   {
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">@result.Item1.Forename, @result.Item1.Surname
                <i class="bi bi-info-circle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight"></i>
                <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                    <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel">@result.Item1.Forename, @result.Item1.Surname</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="offcanvas-body">
                    <Profile4Search Id = "@result.Item1.Id"/>
                </div>
                </div>
            </th>
```

I want to put `offcanvas` for Employee's information but the `Profile4Search` components are not rerendered and always show the same information. How can I rerender the component in foreach loop?

i thought , the component ProfileSearch receive Id from Parameter and show detail of each employees (if user clicks icon)but its rendered only once, and show same Employee's Detail(here the first Employee in loop).

Comment: _"are not rerendered and show always"_ is  a contradiction, please clarify.

Comment: [Polite] Like @HenkHolterman I have no real idea what I'm looking at here.  you need to reduce this down to some structured code that demonstrates your problem.  A block of code with no context is very hard to understand.

Comment: The edit shortened but does not clarify. Try to add expected vs actual results.

Comment: Also, the foreach() loop does not close. That might matter.

Comment: i thought , the component `ProfileSearch` receive Id from Parameter and show detail of each employees (if user clicks icon)but its rendered only once, and show same Employee's Detail(here the first Employee in loop).....

Comment: actually i closed the foreach loop and there is more code under but too long and not related....

Comment: It's not clear but try to replace `(Employee, int)` wit `var` and remove all the `.Item1` (so, just `@result.Id`). You never use `Item2`.

Comment: Are you in Korea?  I am in Korea, maybe I can help, let me know.  Anyway, the whole thing I'm seeing looks like you're trying to mash together existing JavaScript DOM manipulations with Blazor.  I suspect that you could achieve all your goals with much simpler and cleaner code.

Comment: @짜요짜요 what is the *actual* output? Post the actual HTML generated. It's unclear whether you get the same row over and over, if you want to redraw the table to display new data, or if you want to display a selected object somewhere else. What `Profile4Search` component are you talking about? Is `offcanvas` a CSS rule? A CSS rule affects how HTML *renders*. Re-render means displaying something *again* for some reason, eg after a change

Comment: <tr @key="@result" > or <tr @key="@result.Item1.Id" >

Answer (score -2):

When using a for-each loop in C# it's often necessary to assign the loop variable to a temporary variable.

```cs
@foreach ((Employee, int) result in searchResults)
   {
       var tmp = result.Item1;
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">@tmp.Forename, @tmp.Surname
```

Not easy to be certain that is the cause here as your question isn't quite clear on what is / is-not being rendered.
More: [Why is a temporary variable required in foreach to be included in lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856005/why-is-a-temporary-variable-required-in-foreach-to-be-included-in-lambda-express)

Comment: No, a `foreach()`  doesn't need this workaround.

Comment: `it's often necessary to assign the loop variable` no, it's never necessary. It may be convenient, if you need to access nested objects and properties, but never necessary. What you linked to describes issues with *lambdas*, not `foreach`